# What is this moth-like bug on my tree?

Tags: identification, pests

Check out what I found today on my 2 year old tree.
It's about 2 to 3 inches in length not including those massive wings.

[image: side profile of bug]
[glorious full size picture](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/zIgrUCPfh97B_VLn0ODRsL3mpz-C7UdROThjVQxep7c?feat=directlink)

[image: top view of bug]
[full size #2](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/XUpv9rAuc3wojk4Hnh1Eq73mpz-C7UdROThjVQxep7c?feat=directlink)

The tree is a Texas Mountain Laurel and this is central Texas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [cicada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cicada). I found this quote "[East central Texas is a veritable cicada paradise](http://www.texasento.net/Cicada3.htm)". They are harmless to people but the females lay eggs deep within tree limbs. If you notice a loud sound during the hottest part of the day in the vicinity it may be the song of the cicada.

No action is necessary on your part as they prefer larger trees for their eggs.

Comment: Thanks! Based on [austin bug](http://www.austinbug.com/cicadidae.html), it's the Tibicen superba aka the Superb Dog-Day Cicada.